# "To experience" in German

Tags: grammar, difference

Can anyone help me to differentiate *erfahren* and *erleben*?

Comment: Please also note that questions asking for differences are off-topic unless prior research effort is indicated. See also [How do I ask good, on-topic questions for translations or about differences?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/628/2594).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Funny enough, that the duplicate one is not closed and even got 19 upvotes until now.

Comment: @Em1: Well, at least it does report the result of a dictionary search. (It’s still poorly asked by today’s standards.)